# como gener un array json en javascript adicionando id

Tags: javascript, json

Como puedo realizar un script en donde pueda cargar en un json la siguiente estructura, la idea es cargar los valores con push.

1{1,2,3,4,5,6},2{10,11,12,13,14}

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, una solución para tu problema pasaría por lo siguiente: crear un objeto json que tenga la siguiente estructua:

```
var jsonObject1 = {
    'id': 1,
    'arrayNumeros': [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
var jsonObject2 = {
        'id': 2,
        'arrayNumeros': [10,11,12,13,14]
    }
```

De esta manera tendrías un array de jsonObject tal que así:

```
var arrayJsonObjects = [];

arrayJsonObjects.push(jsonObject1);
arrayJsonObjects.push(jsonObject2);
```

Con lo que te daría la siguiente salida:

```
[{"id":1,"arrayNumeros":[1,2,3,4,5,6]},{"id":2,"arrayNumeros":[10,11,12,13,14]}]
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, saludos!!